# Local storage value is not rendering in prod, but does in dev

Tags: angular, jwt, local-storage, angular14

In my Angular app, I'm using locale storage to store a jwt token.
I can't figure out why I get "AUTH_TOKEN" (the key name), instead of the value. Only in prod (works fine with dev profile).

[image: sc]

```
localStorage.setItem('AUTH_TOKEN', value);
localStorage.getItem('AUTH_TOKEN');
```

Answer (score 0):

That is probably because in prod, `value` is set to `AUTH_TOKEN`. Console.log value in prod and see if you can identify the issue. You are probably setting value of `value` differently in prod then in dev.

Comment: No, the value is set to the correct value in prod as in dev.